# How to manually trigger click event in ReactJS?

Tags: html, reactjs

How can I manually trigger a click event in **ReactJS**?
When a user clicks on element1, I want to automatically trigger a click on the `input` tag.

```html
<div className="div-margins logoContainer">
  <div id="element1" className="content" onClick={this.uploadLogoIcon}>
    <div className="logoBlank" />
  </div>
  <input accept="image/*" type="file" className="hide"/>
</div>
```

Comment: Looking at some external libraries, it seems a good idea to make the input element programmatically: https://github.com/okonet/react-dropzone/blob/master/src/index.js#L7

Comment: I can't see why you would ever want to do this in React. What are you looking to do?

Comment: @tobiasandersen It is a perfectly valid use-case to programmatically focus an `input` element, which is likely what the asker wants to accomplish with the programmatically triggered click.

Comment: Yeah sure, both focus and blur are perfectly valid. But clicking? The reason I'm asking is that if e.g. focusing is the use case, then it's better to show that. But if click really is the use case, then it's better to just call the handler.

Comment: @JohnWhite Well it could be bound correctly :) But you're probably right, and it wasn't my meaning to come off snarky. Just wanted to see what the real intention behind this was.

Answer (score 165, accepted):

You could use the [`ref`](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/more-about-refs.html) prop to acquire a reference to the underlying [HTMLInputElement](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLInputElement) object through a callback, store the reference as a class property, then use that reference to later trigger a click from your event handlers using the [HTMLElement.click](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/click) method.

In your `render` method:

```
<input ref={input => this.inputElement = input} ... />
```

In your event handler:

```
this.inputElement.click();
```

Full example:

```
class MyComponent extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div onClick={this.handleClick}>
        <input ref={input => this.inputElement = input} />
      </div>
    );
  }

  handleClick = (e) => {
    this.inputElement.click();
  }
}
```

*Note the [ES6 arrow function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions) that provides the correct lexical scope for `this` in the callback. Also note, that the object you acquire this way is an object akin to what you would acquire using `document.getElementById`, i.e. the actual DOM-node.*

Comment: This is not working for me. Not sure if it's out of date, but I successfully assign the element, but when I call `click` on it, `click` is undefined. I can see all the other attributes and callbacks that I've assigned to that element. Any ideas?

Comment: @TheJKFever -- It's impossible to tell without knowing your code, but it is likely that the reference you are obtaining is in-fact _not_ an `HTMLInputElement` object. What does `instanceof this.inputElement` give?

Comment: this doesn't work for me either, click is undefined.

Comment: @TheJKFever Refs no longer return a document DOM node, they return reference to a React virtual DOM node. To get a reference to the document node, import `ReactDOM` and use `const domNode = ReactDOM.findDOMNode(ref)`.

Comment: "Refs no longer return a document DOM node, they return reference to a React virtual DOM node"

That's definitely a misconception. Refs don't return "virtual DOM" nodes. Source: I work on React.

Comment: @DanAbramov So what's the recommended method for this ?

Comment: @JohnWeisz Thank you soooooo much, it worked for me, I had this necessity to handle with click outside of Form because I hade to put some elements between the button and form.

Comment: Works for me. I put the input element at -100 with absolute position, then in my code `ref={(ref)=>{this.fileUploadRef = ref}` and then my button `onClick={()=>{this.fileUploadRef.click()}}`

Comment: @TheJKFever  
If you're in TypeScript, click might be undefined because input is of type; `HTMLInputElement | null;`, therefore use: `onClick={() => { if(inputElement) (inputElement).click(); } }` to get it to compile!

Comment: Heads-up that if you do an `e.preventDefault()` in your event handler this won't work.

Comment: In functional components it worked perfectly for me using the useRef hook. I used it in the KeyDown event

Comment: While it may work, using this solution with ``e.preventDefault()`` doesn't seem to be good practice. As a workaround, you can include it in an if statement: ``if (e) e.preventDefault()``.

Answer (score 46):

Here is the Hooks solution:

```
import React, {useRef} from 'react';

const MyComponent = () => {
    const myRefname= useRef<HTMLInputElement>(null);
    const handleClick = () => {
        myRefname.current.focus();
     }

    return (
        <div onClick={handleClick}>
            <input ref={myRefname}/>
        </div>
    );
}
```

Comment: "myRefname.current.focus is not a function"

Comment: @Spoderman4 Just assign a type to the `useRef` function. For example: `const myRef = useRef<HTMLInputElement>(null);`

Comment: good answer, using `myRefname.current.click();`

Answer (score 32):

Got the following to work May 2018 with ES6 
React Docs as a reference: https://reactjs.org/docs/refs-and-the-dom.html

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
class AddImage extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.fileUpload = React.createRef();
    this.showFileUpload = this.showFileUpload.bind(this);
  }
  showFileUpload() {
    this.fileUpload.current.click();
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <div className="AddImage">
        <input
          type="file"
          id="my_file"
          style={{ display: "none" }}
          ref={this.fileUpload}
        />
        <input
          type="image"
          src="http://www.graphicssimplified.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/04/upload-cloud.png"
          width="30px"
          onClick={this.showFileUpload}
        />
      </div>
    );
  }
}
export default AddImage;
```

Comment: This looks like more **React Oriented** answer.

Comment: Use innerRef={this.fileUpload} instead of  ref={this.fileUpload} in ReactJS. Rest all code is working file.

Answer (score 10):

You can use `ref` callback which will return the `node`. Call `click()` on that node to do a programmatic click.

Getting the `div` node

```
clickDiv(el) {
  el.click()
}
```

Setting a `ref` to the `div` node

```
<div 
  id="element1"
  className="content"
  ref={this.clickDiv}
  onClick={this.uploadLogoIcon}
>
```

Check the fiddle

https://jsfiddle.net/pranesh_ravi/5skk51ap/1/

Hope it helps!

Comment: when you link to a jsfiddle, it's concidered a good practise to put at least the relevant code in here (btw: the snippet editor supports reactjs as well)

Comment: It is worth noting that while the string ref approach is not deprecated, it is considered legacy functionality that is superseded by the callback-based syntax: `ref={elem => this.elem = elem}` -- This is detailed in [Refs to Components](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/more-about-refs.html).

Comment: @JohnWhite Valid suggestion. Updated the answer!

Comment: Also, you need to check and make sure `el` isn't null/undefined before you do that.

Answer (score 9):

In a functional component this principle also works, it's just a slightly different syntax and way of thinking.

```
const UploadsWindow = () => {
  // will hold a reference for our real input file
  let inputFile = '';

  // function to trigger our input file click
  const uploadClick = e => {
    e.preventDefault();
    inputFile.click();
    return false;
  };

  return (
    <>
      <input
        type="file"
        name="fileUpload"
        ref={input => {
          // assigns a reference so we can trigger it later
          inputFile = input;
        }}
        multiple
      />

      <a href="#" className="btn" onClick={uploadClick}>
        Add or Drag Attachments Here
      </a>
    </>
  )

}
```

Answer (score 8):

```
this.buttonRef.current.click();
```

Comment: this fix my problem, I don't know why people unvote this code

Comment: yes, it requires more context about `useRef`, such we can find in other answers, but that's definitely the answer as of today / 2023

Answer (score 6):

Riffing on Aaron Hakala's answer with useRef inspired by this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/54316368/3893510

```
const myRef = useRef(null);

  const clickElement = (ref) => {
    ref.current.dispatchEvent(
      new MouseEvent('click', {
        view: window,
        bubbles: true,
        cancelable: true,
        buttons: 1,
      }),
    );
  };
```

And your JSX:

```
<button onClick={() => clickElement(myRef)}>Click<button/>
<input ref={myRef}>
```

Answer (score 5):

Using React Hooks and the [`useRef` hook](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#useref).

```js
import React, { useRef } from 'react';

const MyComponent = () => {
    const myInput = useRef(null);

    const clickElement = () => {
        // To simulate a user focusing an input you should use the
        // built in .focus() method.
        myInput.current?.focus();

        // To simulate a click on a button you can use the .click()
        // method.
        // myInput.current?.click();
    }

    return (
        <div>
            <button onClick={clickElement}>
                Trigger click inside input
            </button>
            <input ref={myInput} />
        </div>
    );
}
```

Comment: For me this wasn't working as click and focus were not available.

But what did work is this answer, https://stackoverflow.com/a/54316368/3893510

if instead of trying to do  

myInput.current?.click(); 

You do:

    myInput.current.dispatchEvent(
      new MouseEvent('click', {
        view: window,
        bubbles: true,
        cancelable: true,
        buttons: 1,
      }),
    );

It should work

Comment: What is the meaning of ? in myInput.current?.focus();

Comment: @JuliodeLeon it is "optional chaining" - introduced recently in JavaScript
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Optional_chaining

It's used when you want to access or a call a function on an object that may be undefined.

Answer (score 2):

Try this and let me know if it does not work on your end:

```
<input type="checkbox" name='agree' ref={input => this.inputElement = input}/>
<div onClick={() => this.inputElement.click()}>Click</div>
```

Clicking on the `div` should simulate a click on the `input` element

Answer (score 1):

```
  let timer;
  let isDoubleClick = false;

  const handleClick = () => {
    if(!isDoubleClick) {
      isDoubleClick = true;
      timer = setTimeout(() => {
        isDoubleClick = false;
        props.onClick();
      }, 200);
    } else {
      clearTimeout(timer);
      props.onDoubleClick();
    }
  }

return <div onClick={handleClick}></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

for typescript you could use this code to avoid getting type error

```js
import React, { useRef } from 'react';

const MyComponent = () => {
    const fileRef = useRef<HTMLInputElement>(null);

    const handleClick = () => {
      fileRef.current?.focus();
    }

    return (
        <div>
            <button onClick={handleClick}>
                Trigger click inside input
            </button>
            <input ref={fileRef} />
        </div>
    );
}
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

If it doesn't work in the latest version of reactjs, try using innerRef

```
class MyComponent extends React.Component {


  render() {
    return (
      <div onClick={this.handleClick}>
        <input innerRef={input => this.inputElement = input} />
      </div>
    );
  }

  handleClick = (e) => {
    this.inputElement.click();
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
  imagePicker(){
        this.refs.fileUploader.click();
        this.setState({
            imagePicker: true
        })
    }
```

```html
  <div onClick={this.imagePicker.bind(this)} >
  <input type='file'  style={{display: 'none'}}  ref="fileUploader" onChange={this.imageOnChange} /> 
  </div>
```

**This work for me**

Answer (score -4):

How about just plain old js ?
example:

```
autoClick = () => {
 if (something === something) {
    var link = document.getElementById('dashboard-link');
    link.click();
  }
};
  ......      
var clickIt = this.autoClick();            
return (
  <div>
     <Link id="dashboard-link" to={'/dashboard'}>Dashboard</Link>
  </div>
);
```

Comment: Expectaion is in React

Comment: Manipulating the dom directly is discouraged in react and for the right reasons. storing a reference with `useRef` hook is a much better implementation.

Comment: yep I did not say anything about best practice above is the hackey way but it works