# trigger click on component programmatically

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a div that wrap a component

```
clickComponentA = () => {
   //how to trigger a click on ComponentA?
}
render(){
   return(<div onClick={this.clickComponentA}>
    <ComponentA />
    </div>)
}
```

And for some reason the ComponentA has height 1px; how can I trigger a click on ComponentA when user click on somewhere else? like click on the div tag?

Comment: wasn't this question answered here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39913863/how-to-manually-trigger-click-event-in-reactjs

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to manually trigger click event in ReactJS?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39913863/how-to-manually-trigger-click-event-in-reactjs)

Comment: @Yuval can you take a look on this? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43295907/trigger-react-dropzone-with-ref-doesnt-work